# How to locate next element after text found in b tag - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to extract the text value following a b tag that contains specific text. I'm using Selenium web driver with Python3.

The HTML inspected for the value I'm trying to return (11,847) is here:

[image: HTML of desired Xpath]

This has an Xpath below (I'm not using this xpath directly to find the element as the table construction changes for different examples that I plan to iterate through):

`/html/body/form[1]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()`

As an example, when I print the below it returns Att: i.e. the element located by my search for the text 'Att' within the b tags.

`att=driver.find_element("xpath",".//b[contains(text(), 'Att')]").text`

`print(att)`

Is there a way I can return the value following `<b>Att:</b>` by searching for 'Att:' (or conversly, I'd also like to return the value following `<b>Ref:</b>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`11,847` text content belongs to `td` node.
You can locate this `td` element by it's child `b` text content.
Then you will be able to retrieve the entire text content of that `td` node.
It will contain `Att:` and extra spaces and the desired `11,847` string.
Now you will need to remove the `Att:` and extra spaces so only `11,847` will remain.
As following:

```py
#get the entire text content
entire_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[.//b[contains(text(), 'Att')]]").text
#get the child node text content
child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//b[contains(text(), 'Att')]").text
#remove child text content from entire text content
goal_text = entire_text.replace(child_text,'')
#trim white spaces
goal_text = goal_text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find_element_by_xpath() method to locate the element that contains the text 'Att:' and then use the find_element_by_xpath() method again to locate the following text node. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
att_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[contains(text(), 'Att:')]")
att_value = att_element.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::text()').text
print(att_value)
```

This will locate the element that contains the text 'Att:', then locate the following text node, and return the text value of that node.

Similarly you can use the same xpath for 'Ref:' as well just change the text part to 'Ref:'

```
ref_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[contains(text(), 'Ref:')]")
ref_value = ref_element.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::text()').text
print(ref_value)
```

Note that this will only work if the text value you're trying to extract is immediately following the element that contains 'Att:' or 'Ref:' in a text node.

Answer (score 0):

The following *`xpath`* would result in an error:

```
/html/body/form[1]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()
```

as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) returns only WebElements but not objects.

---

### Solution

The text *`11,847`* is within a text node which is the second decendent of the `<td>` node. So to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH* and *childNodes[n]*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='initial']//td[@align='right']")))).strip())
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='initial']//td[@align='right']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```